# VB.net: Accessing data from DataList in Page_Load

Tags: vb.net

New to VB.net, and trying to re-factor an 'old-skool' ASP page where all the page logic is happening on the .aspx page itself, to code-behind. Basically, I have a button that has a state, either on or off. If on, I set a hidden field to 1, if off, I set it to 0 (the default when a user visits the page).

The goal is to simply change the message I am sending to the user.

Have the following relevant code in `MyPage.aspx`:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfldState" runat="server" Visible="false" Value="0" />

<div id="mainContent">
    <asp:Literal ID="lblMessage" runat="server" 
        Visible="false" />

    <asp:DataList ID="dlList" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="sdsList"
        DataKeyField="Entry No_" 
        RepeatLayout="Flow">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hlCurriculum" runat="server"  
                    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title") %>'  
                    NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "File Path") %>'
                    ToolTip='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title") %>'
                    Target="_blank"
                    Style="font-weight: bold;">
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</div> 

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsList" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="..." 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Entry No_], [Title], [File Path] FROM [Table] WHERE ([State] = @State)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hfldState" Name="State" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And the following in the Page_Load Sub:

```
If Page.IsPostBack Then
    ' Check for results
    dlList.DataBind()

    If dlList.Items.Count > 0 Then
        ' Results, display them
        lblMessage.Text = "<h3>Results</h3>"
        lblMessage.Visible = True
    Else
        ' No results
        lblMessage.Text = "<p>No Results</p>"
        lblMessage.Visible = True
    End If
Else
    ' user has not clicked anything
    lblMessage.Text = "<p>Click button!</p>"
End If
```

The above code produces the following effect: when I click the button, setting the state to 1 and the page reloads, in `Page_Load`, I am getting zero results from the `If dlList.Items.Count > 0 Then` check, and thus am showing the 'No results' message, but the actual `asp:DataList` on the `MyPage.aspx` page is returning results... and then if I click the button again, setting it back to 0, in `Page_Load`, the datalist is now returning results, so I set the text to 'Results', but again, the control on the `MyPage.aspx` page behaves correctly, and shows no results, as expected. Now keep in mind that the above works perfectly in terms of checking the number of results if I move the `If dlList.Items.Count > 0 Then` page logic out of Page_Load and back to the `MyPage.aspx` file, it all works fine (i.e. results when state = 1, none when state = 0)

Any ideas?

Comment: but in this case whether you load a page or post back your load event doesn't check this.  You need to check if you're at a post back or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue related to my ignorance of the page lifecycle in VB.net. Solution was to adjust the visibility of the `asp:Literal`, `asp:DataList`, set values etc in `Page_PreRenderComplete`. Basically, the `asp:DataList` wasn't being set in `Page_Load`, as expected, so doing any kind of logic in `Page_Load` based on the item count didn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see a check in your page load for a postback:

```
If Not IsPostBack
 'code
  dList.DataBind() 'here is where you want to bind the data...
end if
```

Comment: Sorry, updated code to show full code from Page_Load - I do have the IsPostBack check in there.

Comment: @Paul - But dont you want `NOT IsPostBack`?  Please look real careful at my code and compare with yours.  Otherwise you are binding on any postbacks.

Comment: Would I not want to bind the data only when I have something that has been posted to the page, in this case, the button click setting the state?

Comment: @Paul - when your page first loads it's not considered a post back.  If your initial hidden field (the button value) is 0 your current if condition will not execute, is that what you want?

Comment: Exactly. When page loads, I show a 'click button' message, then when user starts clicking and alternating state, I check to see if that state results in anything from the database.

Comment: @Paul do you know how to use the debugger?  Set a break point and check if dList is null / nothing.

Comment: The value of `dlList.Items.Count` is 0. The issues, per my question above, seems to be that the state value stored in the hidden field appears to be wrong, when I click and make state 1, in Page_Load state is 0, and vice-versa.

Comment: @Paul why are you using all these states?  I guess I don't understand your business processes but as a user if I see a form with a button that says click me to me that is just odd.  Why not load the page with the data, what is the point of having the click ?

Comment: I'm attempting to simplify the problem by presenting it as one button/state... there are actually 10 buttons that act as filters to a dataset - i.e. click a button to filter the data.